# Button and input heights are different after setting to the same amount

Tags: html, css

I created this JSFiddle 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wowsk/edj2j7p6/) and if you notice the button and input heights are different when they should be the same (40px). If you add 6px to the buttons height though they are the same. First of all is there a fix to this, such as margin or padding and why is it that this occurs? I have tried it on Firefox and Google Chrome and both turn out the same way.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" class="sameHeight">
<button id="button" class="sameHeight">Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.sameHeight{
    height:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can with:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This should help

More info about `box-sizing` here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what cs.edoardo wrote you should watch out for possible Firefox quirks:

```
/*
  Getting rid of the extra 2px padding for submit
  buttons and inputs in Firefox 4+.
  Whoever thought that was fun to implement... Òó grmlhmpfargh
*/
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```